# custom library addition in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am making a static cpp libray with extension .h and I have written source code for the same in a different file with .cpp extension. Now I want to make a test script that will include the custom library that I just created. When I include this libary using 
`#include<mylibrary.h>`and try to run this test file, I get an error saying **No such file or directory compilation terminated.**

I know that I am getting this error because nowhere I have specified the path for same for the complier to look for this file as I used to do in Visual Studio environment. How to do the same in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This is using Visual Studio, right, the compiler, with the Visual Studio Code editor?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code IDE on LInux machine

Comment: you should use a build tool, like CMake, or GNU Make, to configure the project so it knows where to find the includes. Using `-I` simply will work, as Gmork says below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The location of your .h file needs to be either in your compiler libraries folders or in the folder where you execute g++/clang++ or whatever compiler you use.

These are the default search-paths but you can add additional ones by adding
the flag 
`-I path/to/folder` in your tasks.json (or makefile if you are using one).

Comment: Gmork can you please guide me to some link where this type of flag adding to tasks.json file is done.

Comment: If you are able to execute your program, you should have a tasks.json in your '.vscode'-folder. Open this file.
You should find a line like `"command": "g++ filename",`. Add another line after this: 
`"args": [
"-I",
"path/to/includefolder"
]`. And that's it.

You can use special variables to get for example the path to your project folder with the ones mentioned here at 'Variable substitution':
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks